# Package `README` figures giving "non-standard" naming NOTE

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm building an R package, and have a few plots included in my `README` documentation. I'm using what seems to be the standard `knitr` options:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>",
  fig.path = "README-"
)
```

which is creating 2 files in the package root directory:

```
README-plotButterfly-1.png
README-plotChlorophyll-1.png
```

This is giving me a `NOTE` when running `check` (I'm using RStudio's `build` panel for this):

```
checking top-level files ... NOTE
Non-standard files/directories found at top level:
   'README-plotButterfly-1.png' 'README-plotChlorophyll-1.png'
R CMD check results 0 errors | 0 warnings | 1 note
```

I've also tried putting the images into a subfolder (my preference here) `READMEfigs/` but got the same `NOTE` message.

I'm finding a lot of packages with similar naming structure to mine, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong (or at least ill-advised), or is this `NOTE` just one to be ignored? I'm not trying to get my package on `CRAN`, but I would like it to be as tidy and "standards compliant" as possible.

Comment: Try adding `^README-.*\.png$` to your `.Rbuildignore` file.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell, that does it. I'm going with the sub-folder `READMEfigs`, and adding that to `.Rbuildignore`, and that works to get rid of the note. Is there any reason to stick with the standard (in the root directory) naming? (PS: please feel free to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it).

Comment: To add, if you create a README with devtools, this happens automatically for you (with some other perks). See https://rdrr.io/cran/devtools/man/use_readme_rmd.html